# Override protected _toHtml() method

Tags: overrides, ce-1.8.1.0, catalogsearch, autocomplete

I am trying to override `_toHtml()` method of class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete` like below :

**app/etc/modules/Custom_Autocomplete.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Autocomplete>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_CatalogSearch/>
            </depends>
        </Custom_Autocomplete>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Autocomplete/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Autocomplete>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_Autocomplete>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <autocomplete>
                <class>Custom_Autocomplete_Block</class>
            </autocomplete>
            <catalogsearch>
                <rewrite>
                    <autocomplete>Custom_Autocomplete_Block_Autocomplete</autocomplete>
                </rewrite>
            </catalogsearch>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/Autocomplete/Block/Autocomplete.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_Autocomplete_Block_Autocomplete extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete {

    protected function _toHtml() {
        // My Custom Code
    }

}
```

This is not working.

Mage_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Search_Suggest is already extending Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete. Now, how can I extend Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete and override _toHtml()

Please help me out to make it work.

Comment: why do you want to override it? Is there an event you can use instead?

Comment: Check if this block is overriden by another module.

Comment: @SeStro Yes, Mage_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Search_Suggest is extending Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete. Now, how can I extend Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete and override _toHtml()

Comment: tried to  extend block Mage_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Search_Suggest

Comment: `Mage_XmlConnect_Block_Catalog_Search_Suggest` simply extends the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete` class, it doesn't rewrite it. If you are unable to make it work, then check basic things first like whether your module is working at all. Then, put some debugging statements in core file to check if it is being fired at all. You'll get better idea about what's going on in the system